# MFMessageComposer iPhone,Auto Message Send

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, message, sendmessage

Any one know how to implement auto send message  using MFMessageComposer....i mean No need of displaying The message Composer..we Have to sent the pre-defined message  to a given Number..Or any other way without using MFMessageComposer..???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't auto-send messages with MFMessageComposer. It always displays the message to the user before sending (and rightly so).

An alternative would be to call a webservice which dispatches an email to you. Or put enough SMTP code in your app to get emails sending. You'll need your own email system for this though as you'll not be able to get the users email settings.

Comment: Thank you Tony, But i want to send SMS not Emails...teh problem with messagecomposer is when i am dismissing the message box my view frame changed